# How to use dynamic data when using FlutterFlow Table Calendar plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, custom-widgets, flutterflow

I'm using this custom widget [package](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart). I have gotten the package to work but i'm quite new to FlutterFlow and don't understand how to use it with dynamic data from an API. I want to pass a parameter and pass the API results through that.

I have imported [utils.dart](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/utils.dart) code manually in to the custom widget file since I can't add other files to it. This all works fine.

The section I'm stuck is within the utils.dart file.

```
final _kEventSource = Map.fromIterable(List.generate(50, (index) => index),
 key: (item) => DateTime.utc(kFirstDay.year, kFirstDay.month, item * 5),
 value: (item) => List.generate(
    item % 4 + 1, (index) => Event('Event $item | ${index + 1}')))
..addAll({
 kToday: [
  Event('Today\'s Event 1'),
  Event('Today\'s Event 2'),
 ],
});
```

I think I need to convert this section to somehow accept a parameter.